# UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin with Reference to Superview on iOS

Tags: ios, autoresizingmask

I'm dynamically adding an error icon to fields in a form as shown here:

[image: error icon]

I'm generating the icon in code, and I want to position it on the **top-right** of its superview, but I can't get it to go where I want it. The screenshot shows how it stays on the left, but it should be on the right.

Here's my code:

```
//Create the image
UIImageView *errorIcon =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10,-10,23,23)];

//Set the image file
errorIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"];

//Tell the image to position it on the top-right (flexible left margin, flexible bottom margin)
errorIcon.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

No matter what I set the frame's x value to, I can't get it to stick on the right.

What am I doing wrong with the `frame` and/or the `autoResizingMask`?

Comment: This will be a *lot* easier to do if you are on iOS 6 and use autolayout instead of `autoresizingMask`. `autoresizingMask` does not position anything! It is up to you to set the position correctly. But autolayout positions the thing exactly with relation to other stuff, and keeps it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
UIImageView *errorIcon = 
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10,-10,23,23)];
```

That means the top left of the superview. If that isn't where you want to put it, don't put it there!

The top right is here:

```
UIImageView *errorIcon = 
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(superview.bounds.size.width-10,-10,23,23)];
```

(For `superview` substitute a reference to the view that will be the superview.)

Comment: Not a charm, though; just a knowledge of what a frame and bounds is. If you'd like to know about frame and bounds too, read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_frame

Answer (score 1):

Autoresizing rules only kick in when you resize the view or superview, it's not for setting initial position. Plus your error icon origin `(-10, -10)` is just outside top left corner. What you probably need is just:

```
UIImageView *errorIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:errorImage];
errorIcon.center = CGPointMake(yourFieldView.frame.size.width, 0);
[yourFieldView addSubview:errorIcon];
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty much the same as the other. Thanks for your help!